# Getting Name of Facebook page on which App is installed in JSP/Javascript

Tags: facebook, jsp, jakarta-ee

I want to get Name of Facebook page on which my FB App is installed.The app is built in JSP & it is rendered in an Iframe on canvas page.

I have gone through a similar question asked [here](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/7623848/how-to-tell-which-facebook-page-my-page-tab-app-is-installed-on) but that explains the way to achieve this in PHP. I have also found another implementation on C#.

But I didn't find any implementation using jsp. Please suggest a  solution either in JSP or even Javascript would do this for me.

Regards
Yogesh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a solution [sergiy's site](http://www.sergiy.ca/how-to-implement-facebook-oauth-2.0-app-authorization-process-in-java/) which explains authorization flow in detail! Superb explanation indeed! I Just tweaked lines after obtaining JSON object (data) as

`String PageId=((JSONObject)data.get("page")).getString("id");`